# Get a list of installed programs and applications

Tags: software-installation, upgrade

Three years ago I worked for some period with Ubuntu 14.04.

I am familiar with the command line. My question are the following:

1) How can I use the command line to get a .txt version of a list containing all the installed programs and applications?

2) After installing, with a bootable USB, the version 16.04 (I have already created the USB and use to install this version to another computer so I am already familiar with the relevant procedure), how can I use the aforementioned list in order to install the programs and applications installed initially (i.e., before the upgrading)?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: your answer can be found here [link] https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: Merci! I accept the duplicate nature immediately.